# how do I access struct enum values for use with UIsearchbar?

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I am struggling to learn about creating and using more complex structs with UITableView and UIsearchbar.  I have a table that displays the following structs in 2 sections.

```
struct ReceiveInResponse: Codable {

    var result: [ReceiveIn]

}

struct ReceiveIn: Codable {

    var section: String
    var items: [ReceiveInComp]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case section = "Section"
        case items
    }

}

struct ReceiveInComp: Codable {

   let owner, barcode, quantity: String
   let resultDescription, status: String

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case owner = "Owner"
      case barcode = "Barcode"
      case quantity = "Quantity"
      case resultDescription = "Description"
      case status = "Status"
   }

}
```

I have implemented the searchbar many times. But this time I am getting an error when trying to search the value of case barcode.  This is the error.

```
Type '[ReceiveInComp]' has no member 'barcode'
```

Here is my code

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    
    self.filteredList = []

    if (searchText == "") {
        self.filteredList = self.ReviewList
    } else {
        for comp in self.ReviewList {
            
            let myitems = comp.items
```

attempt 1

```
            switch myitems {

                case .barcode(let barcode): do { // error thrown here
                    if (barcode.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) {
                        self.filteredList.append(comp)
                    }
                }
            }
```

attempt 2
var barcode = myitems.barcode // error thrown here

```
            if (barcode.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) {
                self.filteredList.append(comp)
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I can print myitems to console and see the values it contains.  How do I access the value of barcode for comparison to searchtext?

Here is a sample of what I see when I do print(myitems) in console

```
App.ReceiveInComp(owner: "E3D Rental", barcode: "10021640", quantity: "1", resultDescription: "2X2. X42 BLK CABINET ", status: "missing"),
```

SOLUTION

```
        for comp in self.ReviewList {
            
            let myitems = comp.items
            
            for item in myitems{
                
                let barcode = item.barcode
                if (barcode.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) {
                    self.filteredList.append(comp)
                }
                
                
            }
}
```

this seems to work, getting duplicates in the search results for some reason but prior error is gone. thanks @shadowrun

Comment: enum CodingKeys is for encoding purpose .

Comment: Error says Type '[ReceiveInComp]' has no member 'barcode' - means an Array of Things doesn't have a property of a single Thing, does that help? for item in myitems perhaps?

Comment: I posted a sample of what I see in console.  How do you access the value of "barcode" so it can be used to compare with search text?